# Creating a React app with 'create-react-app my-app' for the first time

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to create a react app for the fist time on my local machine. I've successfully installed 'create-react-app' globally using 'npm i -g create-react-app' After I installed it, when I try to create a react app using 'create-react-app' it creates the app's folder with only two files in it, which are [the items within the created folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVvza.png) However, the terminal displays this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'cra-template/package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\East-Sound\Desktop\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\init.js
- C:\Users\East-Sound\Desktop\contactsudacity\[eval]
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:98:19)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\East-Sound\Desktop\node_modules\react-scripts\sc
ripts\init.js:117:13)
    at [eval]:3:14
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:134:12)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:310:38)
    at internal/process/execution.js:81:19
    at [eval]-wrapper:6:22
    at evalScript (internal/process/execution.js:80:60)
    at internal/main/eval_string.js:27:3 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\East-Sound\\Desktop\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\scripts\\init.
js',
    'C:\\Users\\East-Sound\\Desktop\\contactsudacity\\[eval]'
  ]
}

Aborting installation.
  node  has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Done.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Did you installed node.js?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know that method you mention of creating a new React app. Why don't you try the standard way?

You’ll need to have Node >= 10.16 and npm >= 5.6 on your machine. To create a project, run:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app

Comment: I have node.js -v=14.17.6, and npm -v=6.14.15. I tried the standard way, yet it gives me the same error